# Can we define django model from csv file or pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, django, csv

I have more than 200 columns in csv file and want to define Class in django model.

But I really can't find handful instructions to create django model from csv files (first row indicates columns)

Is there any way to define django model from csv file or pandas dataframe?

Comment: I think you would struggle, because defining Django models requires types to be specified, which you cannot do from a name alone.

Comment: I guess python pandas can give some hints, since they recognize the types of variables automatically.

Comment: There's too much in a Django model to allow for creation from a raw csv file - even if you have type hints from panda - in a reliable manner (unless that csv file has been written specially to fully describe a Django model of course but I assume it's not what you're talking about here). Think of max length for char field, choices restrictions, min / max / whatever validation etc). The best you can expect is a one-shot script that will creates your models.py skeleton, but you will have to edit it manually anyway.

Comment: Thanks ! It was helpful. I may create a opensource project to do it easily :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generate texts to feed on model based on below codes

```
import numpy as np

for col in speech_data.columns:
    arr = speech_data[col]

    size = 0
    value = ""
    for ar in arr:
        if len(str(ar)) > size:
            size = len(str(ar))
            value = ar

    print col, size, type(speech_data.iloc[0][col]), ar

    if type(speech_data.iloc[0][col]) == np.int64:
        print col + " = " + "models.IntegerField()"

    elif type(speech_data.iloc[0][col]) == str:
        print col + " = " + "models.CharField(max_length="+ str(size+3) +")"

    elif type(speech_data.iloc[0][col]) ==  np.float64:
        print col + " = " + "models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)"    
    elif type(speech_data.iloc[0][col]) ==  np.bool_:
        print col + " = " + "models.BooleanField()"
```